# What is the purpose of united lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

While reading through the [Lens over Tea #1](http://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-1) article, I found the `united` lens. My implementation is

```
united :: Lens' a ()
united f v = const v <$> f ()
```

which is pretty much the same as the [implementation in the Lens library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:united).

What leaves me completely baffled is why would I want a function like this in the first place? Are there any uses of this lens?

Comment: Or just `united f s = s <$ f ()`, it's a bit simpler to read IMH(umble)O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never actually seen or used this before. But I imagine it's useful in the same way as the `id` function (which returns it's argument unmodified) or the `Identity` monad (which is a monad with no "effects"; exactly equivalent to not using monads at all) are useful.

These and other similar concepts (including the `()` type!) are basically "do-nothing" structures, so they seem useless when you look at them by themselves. But they become useful when polymorphism is involved, by giving you a "do-nothing" option to pass to general operations.